# Extra Program Files folder in Win7 and its removal

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

A WIN7SP1 on a Dell laptop showed an extra Program Files folder ('Programme' in German language version). How to get rid of it?

The Dell laptop is from Ebay and the OS seems to have been flashed on to the disk by the vendor from some obscure image he might have had. Nothing else is known about the install procedure of the OS.

[image]

A screenshot from admin account shows an interesting variation.

[image]

Changing the superflous 'Programme' to 'Programs'.

Is this:

1. MSFT multi language pack bug?
2. Screwup of a non localization knowledgeable 3rd party install?

So : How to get rid of it? (Hint: the extra one is empty)

Cheers,
Gert

Comment: Sounds like a folder created manually.  If you don't trust the image, download the .iso from Microsoft and reinstall using the license key.

Answer (score 0):

Is "Programme" empty?  If not, don't touch it.  The US version of Windows has that folder named "Program Files".  (Which you don't have.)  Note that the US version does not call it "Programs" -- that one may be superfluous.

Note that you also have "Benutzer" instead of "Users".

You also have "Documents and Settings" and the German version of it "Dokumente und Einstellungen" which aren't supposed to be there in Win7.  Perhaps it was upgraded from an earlier version of Windows (maybe XP?).

I would reformat and install Win7 from scratch.  That's the safest thing with any computer bought from Ebay.